# Yii2. Получить value выбранного элемента из списка dropDownList

Tags: yii2

Имеется список регионов. При выборе региона нужно сформировать список городов этого региона. Отправляю запрос в контроллер `site/get_cities`, и чтобы сформировать список именно этого региона пытаюсь отправить еще и `id` региона. Но никак не получается, что мне вставить вместо вопросительных знаков?

```
Html::dropDownList(
  'region', 
  $region, 
  ArrayHelper::map($regions_dropdownlist,'id','name'),
  [
    'prompt' => 'Все регионы',
    'onchange' => '$.post(
        "'.Yii::$app->urlManager>createUrl(["site/get_cities", "id" => ??????]).'", 
        function( data ) {
          alert(data);
        }
     )'
  ]
)
```

В итоге хочу создать два селекта, при выборе региона во втором селекте формируется список городов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил таким способом

```
Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['site/get_cities', 'id' => '']).'"+$(this).val()
```